# Complex:Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be analytic such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. Then which of the following are possible values of $f(1/2)=$

> i. $\dfrac{1}{4}$

> ii.$\dfrac{-1}{4}$

> iii.$\dfrac{1}{3}$

> iv.$\dfrac{-1}{3}$

By Schwarz lemma, all the options are correct. But does $f'(0)=0$ shorten the possible value list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\frac {f(z)} {z^{2}}$. Since $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ it follows that $g$ has  removable singularity at $0$. Now $|g(z)| \leq \frac1 {(1-r)^{2}}$ on $|z|=1-r$. By MMP the inequality holds for all $z$ with $|z| \leq 1-r$. Letting $r \to 0$ we see that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z$. Thus, $|f(\frac 1 2)| \leq \frac  1 4$ ruling out iii) and 1v). The first two are possible: just look at $f(z)=z^{2}$ and $f(z)=-z^{2}$.

Comment: ..@Kavi rama sir  can u elaborate little  more  why $|g(z)|\le \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}?$

Comment: @monika That is an immediate consequence of MMP. The maximum of $|g|$ on $\{z: |z| \leq 1-r\}$ is attained on the boundary.